# Differ Android and iOS with Lua

Tags: android, ios, lua

I have a Lua script and it should be executed on Android and **iOS**, so sometimes I need to know if it is being executed on **iOS** or if it is being executed on Android. The only way I found was checking the beginning of `debug.getinfo(1).source`, but I think that there should be a better way.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what context is this script running?

If it is in the context of an existing application or framework, that application should provide you this information. If you are writing the lower-level code calling Lua, you should provide it yourself.

I don't know how you can guess the OS by looking at `debug.getinfo(1).source` by the way. How is it different on iOS and Android?

If you give more details about what you are doing, I will be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: The reason I have to detect on Lua is because the app cant send this information to the Lua Script. With `debug.getinfo(1).source` I could see if the path started with "@/var/mobile/Applications" but maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: If you have no outside way to provide this information, I guess your solution is fine. But I do not see many use cases where you would have no way to provide outside information to your Lua script and still have access to the debug library.

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin method, that I know of. If your script can call `os.execute` and `os.getenv`, you can probably figure out an OS command or an environment variable that would allow you to distinguish. Otherwise whatever runs your script must provide it (possibly through `os.getenv`: for example, doesnt' apache set some environment variable with apache version etc? if this is what runs your script then `os.getenv` should do it).